# Проблема в верстке мобильный браузер

Tags: css

почему на мобильных браузерах стиль `min-width` не работает кроме chrome android:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а это `opera`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без проблемного кода ничего ответить невозможно

Comment: Проблемный код должен быть указан прямо в тексте вопроса без ссылок, а лучше [mcve]

Comment: проблемный код? да в том то и дело что проблем в коде нету но мобильные браузера показывает по разному.

Comment: Если мы не сможем повторить вашу проблему у себя, очень маловероятно, что мы поможем. Если вы ограничитесь ссылкой на сайт, то после его починки другие посетители сайта stackoverflow не смогут воспроизвести проблему и понять суть вопроса, всё это делает ваш вопрос оффтопиком на данном сайте, увы

Comment: К тому же в моём браузере opera проблемы нет https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz2Ee.png

Comment: И даже в opera mini всё отображается нормально

Comment: теперь понятно спасибо, а в других браузерах не проверяли? например us browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил проблема была в `min-width: auto;` заменил на `0px`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/223634)

Comment: Ну а как? я сам не знаю что мне помог? ясно дело что `min-width: auto;` каждый браузер понимает по своему. По этому лучше установить значения.

Comment: @newProgrammer `auto` не является допустимым значением для `min-width`, поэтому бардак совершенно неудивителен